# Using fink to download 'g77'

Tags: fink

I tried to use fink to download 'g77' which is a fortran compiler. This failed because the package doesn't exist.  Does anyone else know where I could download g77?

I'm Mac osx 10.7.2

Comment: Is there any special reason why not to use gfortran which is the official fortran frontend for GCC? As far as I remember, the support for g77 was dropped, since gfortran has full support for previous fortran versions. Also the g77 will probably be part of one of the GCC packages, so you can look there.

Comment: is this available via fink, when i search for gcc the search returns multiple hits.

Comment: I don't have a Mac and don't use fink, but I have some experience with Unix. Based on that, you'd need to install from fink's list gcc46, gcc46-compiler and gcc46-shlibs. The gcc46 should pull the other two as dependencies and should include all official compilers which are part of GCC. On some systems GCC is broken into parts, so you can install some pats and not use other, but that doesn't appear to be the case with fink.